# My XFCE4 icons all almost gone

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce

I am using Archlinux and today I've tried to install a new theme.

When I rebooted the PC, almost all of my icons are gone (as you can see in the screenshot). I've tried to get back the default Tango icons but they are missing too. I've tried reinstalling tango-icon-theme from yaourt (a package manager) but it's still in that state :(

Please tell me how to fix it

[image: XFCE4 icon bug]

Comment: I've edited your question, you can revert the changes or edit it again if you don't like it.

Comment: Thank you. Hope that will help for others to come up with suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like nobody came with solution, I've just reinstalled XFCE4 but Tango did not appear. I've installed Rodentia icon theme and now I have all my icons back.